# Hide Sheet If Another Is Unhidden

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything over here. But what I am trying to do is to hide `Sheet 1` if any sheets name contain **Hello** are unhidden; vice versa. Any idea what went wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
Private Sub HideIrrelevantSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Hello*" Then

        Worksheets("Sheet 1").Visible = xlSheetHidden

    Else
        Worksheets("Sheet 1").Visible = xlSheetVisible

    End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is to hide Sheet 1 if any sheets name contain Hello are unhidden; vice versa.

Then you need to test it the worksheet is visible or not, besides testing the name, perhaps like the following:

```
Private Sub HideIrrelevantSheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "Hello*" Then
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Visible = xlSheetHidden
            Else
                Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
            Exit Sub ' no need to keep looping, or maybe use Exit For
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```